# Tips For Creating simple game .net

Tags: .net, winforms

I am developing a simple backgammon.
i Designed 3 pictures for the game.

1. black not as png format
2. white not ==>png format
3. board jpg

I have some questions about designing the game.
I want to create it with .NET Framework 4, probably under windows
I'm a bit familiar with WPF but not much.

1. what is the best way for putting png nut on the jpg board? picturebox?
2. in attention of first question how can I move nuts on board?

---

If possible give me some tips about developing this game.
Thanks

Comment: @jdehaan .
sorry. thanks for edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What better way to learn than to look at what others have done:

http://sharpcheckers.codeplex.com/

This is Checkers written using MVP (Model View Presenter) so it's a hitch to hook it up to use HTML5, WPF, etc.

Comment: @shaahin I believe the answers to your questions are in the code he linked. Your questions (placing images and moving them) are going to be directly addressed in the code sample.